# Custom Page Type Property with Inheritance

Tags: kentico

I'm looking for advice on how I might implement a custom property on a page type that supports inheritance.

The sort of functionality I'm looking for would be similar to how the "Use output cache" radio buttons work on the Properties > General page in portal mode.

So I want to be able to create a property on a page type, see radio buttons like this, and then based on whether I choose yes, no, or inherit it will go back up the content tree to find the value to apply to that property (if inherit is selected of course).

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand. So you want have a dynamic property for your page based on parent's value at the moment of creation. You can access parent object like so:

```
{%EditedObject.Parent.FieldName%}
```

You may try to create field with radio button control to choose a value.

```
0; No
1; Yes
{%EditedObject.Parent.FieldName%}; Inherit
```

Hope this gives you some ideas